# Uploaded file not save in folder

Tags: php, pdo, phpmyadmin

Im using XAMPP to test this codes on my windows laptop and there is no problem. but when i run on my mac book, file that i want upload wasn't save in upload folder. any solution for me?
this is my php code

```
<?php
$conn=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=xxx', 'root', '') or die(mysql_error());
if(isset($_POST['submit'])!=""){


    $title = $_POST['title'];// file title
    $date = $_POST['date'];// file date
    $ref = $_POST['ref'];// file ref
    $ftype = $_POST['ftype'];// file ref
    $from_to = $_POST['from_to'];// person incharge
    $details = $_POST['details'];// details
    $location = $_POST['location'];// file location
    $status = $_POST['status'];// file status   

  $name=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
  $size=$_FILES['photo']['size'];
  $type=$_FILES['photo']['type'];
  $temp=$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES,"upload/".$name);
$query=$conn->query("INSERT INTO upload(title, date, ref, ftype, from_to, details, location, status, name)VALUES('$title', '$date', '$ref', '$ftype', '$from_to', '$details', '$location', '$status', '$name')");
if($query){
header("location:view.php");
    }
else{
die(mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
```

And this is my form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" name="form" method="post">

        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">

    <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Reference Number</label></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="ref" placeholder="Reference Number" required /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">File Name</label></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" placeholder="File Name" required /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Type</label></td>
        <td><p><select name="ftype" required >
            <option value="Correspondence">Correspondence</option>
</select></p></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Date</label></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="date" name="date" placeholder="Date" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td><label class="control-label">Person Incharge</label></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="from_to" placeholder="Person Incharge" required /></td>
    </tr>

        <td><label class="control-label">Details</label></td>
        <td><textarea class="form-control" name="details" placeholder="Details" required ></textarea> </td>
    </tr>

        <td><label class="control-label">Location</label></td>
        <td><p><select name="location" required >
            <option value="Admin">Admin</option>

</select></p></td>
    </tr>

        <td><label class="control-label">Status</label></td>
        <td><p><select name="status" required >
            <option value="Active">Active</option>
</select></p></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><p>Attach File<input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" required />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

        </td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the upload directory and made sure it is writable by PHP?

Comment: u mean in php.ini? i've checked already.

Comment: No. I mean the actual filesystem.

Comment: file_uploads=On

Comment: how can i check it sir?

Comment: You can use the `ls -l` command to list the permissions of the files and directories of wherever you currently are on the command-line. This has nothing to do with your php.ini file. This is something on your filesystem. I'm noticing something wrong with your code though, so this may be unnecessary.

Comment: i not understand ls -l command sir.

Comment: @emick If you're a Linux user, you can enter `ls -l` command in terminal to list content of current directory

Comment: @ParagJadhav and what i must do after that?

Comment: Then command will be same=> `ls -l`

Comment: @ParagJadhav and what should i do sir?

Comment: 'ls' is one of the most basic commands on a linux-based system.  You should get a lot more informed about an OS before you try to run anything on it. I don't think I'm supposed to recommend any specific textbooks here, but really any one will do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a problem with your code in this section:

```
$name=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
$size=$_FILES['photo']['size'];
$type=$_FILES['photo']['type'];
$temp=$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES,"upload/".$name);
```

`move_uploaded_file` takes a string for its first parameter, not an associative array. You are passing in the entirety of the `$_FILES` superglobal. Instead, you need to specify which file to move. You are already setting a variable to the file's `tmp_name` which is what should be what you pass to `move_uploaded_file`. Try this updated code.

```
$name=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
$size=$_FILES['photo']['size'];
$type=$_FILES['photo']['type'];
$temp=$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($temp,"upload/".$name);
```

Comment: no. just file i want upload didn't save in folder @Cameron Roe

Comment: actually i've try so many way. my windows laptop can save it in folder  but my macbook not.

Comment: If it is still not saving and you updated the code to what I told you to, then you likely are having a file permissions error. You should read a tutorial on the Mac filesystem, bash, and terminal to figure out how to check and set file permissions for your uploads directory. You also need to make sure the directory exists on your Mac.